# show text from another div to another div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do so after selection the form did't disappear. The text was created in div2.
the problem is simplified so I would like a solution on this code.

```
<script>

    function writeStandard() {
        document.write('ticket Standard');
    }
    function writeVip() {
        document.write('ticket Vip');
    }
    function show() {
        document.write('<input type="radio" name="ticket" value="standard" onclick="writeStandard()">Standard');
        document.write('<input type="radio" name="ticket" value="vip" onclick="writeVip()">Vip');
    }

</script>

<body>

    <div id="div1">
        <p>select</p>
        <script>
            show();
        </script>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
        --- I want here the text after clicking ---
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The above code yields ( for me at least ) `Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined`

Comment: You may wish to read [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the text to appear below the radio buttons, instead of `document.write` use `innerHTML`. So you would need to get the element, and then change it's text based on which radio button is pressed.

```html
<script>
function writeStandard() {
 var temp = document.getElementById("div2");
    temp.innerHTML = "ticket Standard";
}
function writeVip() {
    var temp2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    temp2.innerHTML = "ticket Vip";
}
function show() {
    document.write('<input type="radio" name="ticket" value="standard" onclick="writeStandard()">Standard');
    document.write('<input type="radio" name="ticket" value="vip" onclick="writeVip()">Vip');
}

</script>

<body>

<div id="div1">
<p>select</p>
<script>
    show();
</script>
</div>

<div id="div2">
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append a child node to your "div2" element inside the body of the the "writeVip" or "writeStandard" functinons.

Here is an example on how to achieve that for a list element: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Answer (score 1):

```js
function show() {
 let src=document.getElementById('div1');
 let tgt=document.getElementById('div2');
 
 ['standard','vip', 'silver', 'gold', 'platinum', 'diamond'].forEach( text=>{
  let label=document.createElement('label');
   label.innerText=label.for=text;
   
  let input=document.createElement('input');
   input.type='radio';
   input.name='ticket';
   input.value=text;
   
  label.appendChild( input );
  
  input.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   tgt.innerText='ticket '+this.value
  });
  
  src.appendChild( label );
 });
}
        
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', show );
```

```html
<div id="div1">
<p>select</p>
</div>

<div id="div2"></div>
```

Is this more or less what you are trying to achieve? Using `document.write` is only really for initial page load and even then it is of limited use much of the time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function show() {
                let src=document.getElementById('div1');
                let tgt=document.getElementById('div2');

                ['standard','vip'].forEach( text=>{
                    let label=document.createElement('label');
                        label.innerText=label.for=text;

                    let input=document.createElement('input');
                        input.type='radio';
                        input.name='ticket';
                        input.value=text;

                    label.appendChild( input );

                    input.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        tgt.innerText='ticket '+this.value
                    });

                    src.appendChild( label );
                });
            }

            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', show );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            <p>select</p>
        </div>

        <div id="div2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you probably want to do is this.

```
<body>
<div id="div1">
    <p>select</p>
    <input type="radio" name="ticket" value="standard" onclick="writeStandard()"> Standard
    <input type="radio" name="ticket" value="vip" onclick="writeVip()">Vip
</div>
<div id="div2">
    --- I want here the text after clicking ---
</div>
<script>
    var div2=document.getElementById('div2');
    function writeStandard() {
        div2.innerHTML='ticket Standard';
    }
    function writeVip() {
      div2.innerHTML='ticket Vip';
    }
</script>
```

try to learn some basics of javascript selectors then jquery.